# Expected Value of a person to find own seat as on ticket

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value

> Given 50 people who bought airplane tickets. There are seats listed on those tickets, but all passengers except the last one sit in a random seat. The last one decides to take the place on the ticket. How many people will change their seat? Find the expected value if the disturbed person has to find their own seat on the ticket

My approach to the above formulation is taking a random variable X which denotes whether the person finds the listed seat on the ticket which is 1 else 0. The last person chooses from remaining 49 seats, thus probability is $\frac{1}{49}$. Now this will displace the person sitting on the random seat so the probability he can choose his correct seat is $\frac{1}{48}$. Now this process can be repeated as it will displace another person and we get $\frac{1}{47}$ which will displace another person and we get $\frac{1}{46}$ and so on. Thus expected value is the summation of all of them = $\frac{1}{49}+\frac{1}{48}+\frac{1}{47}+\frac{1}{46}+...$. This is done so as to find people changing their seat.

Can you please let me know if the approach to the above formulation is correct?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121014/discussion-on-question-by-ten-do-expected-value-of-a-person-to-find-own-seat-as).

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if I am correct but we can solve it intuitively like supposing two cases i.e. the last person sits on the remaining seat which conforms to the mentioned seat in the ticket or the last person sits on seats excluding the remaining seat. Thus probability of this event is 1/2 same can be done for 49 people as the last person sits on the correct seat and rest of the remaining people are disturbed so we get expected value close to 1/2*49=24.5

Answer (score 0):

I like solving these kinds of problem as follows.

There are 49 people who sit on 49 seats. Consider the random variables $S_1, \dots, S_{49}$, where $S_i$ equals either 1, if the $i$-th passenger is sitting on his ticket seat, or 0, if he is sitting on another seat.

Unfortunately, these random variables are not independent and working with them is usually a mess.

But what the problem is asking is the expected value of $\sum_{i=1}^{49} S_i$. And the linearity of the expected value doesn't need the independence! So, noting that the probability that a single passenger sits on its own seat is $\frac{1}{49}$ and thus $\mathbb{E}(S_i) = \frac{1}{49} \ \forall i $, we can easily compute

$$ \mathbb{E} \left[ \sum_{i=1}^{49} S_i \right] = \sum_{i=1}^{49} \mathbb{E}[S_i] = \sum_{i=1}^{49} \frac{1}{49} = 1 . $$

Thus, the average number of people who will sit on the right seat is 1 and on average 48 people will need to move.

Comment: I probably misunderstood the text of the problem...

Comment: You have, indeed, answered a different question.  You have answered "what is the expected number of passengers who have found their correct seat, given a random permutation."  for that you are correct, though personally I have always found it odd that, regardless of $n$, the expected number of fixed points of a randomly selected permutation on $n$ letters is always $1$.

Comment: It is odd, but still true! :)